# Access denied Mysql ( MySQL57 is missing)

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to install mysql in my computer.

First of all, I installed it in a wrong directory, and I removed the services MySQL and MySQL57.

When I installed it again, setted the environment variable, however only the MySQL service was created (MySQL57) is missing.

When I try to access, I can't acess using root user (Acess denied). In all of tutorials that I have read, is saying that I need to stop the MySQL57, edit the init file and start it again. How can I recover this service?

Thanks from Brazil.

Comment: which OS are you using?

Comment: i'm using windows 10

Answer (score 0):

First, if the password of root is too simple, the mysql server will deny your access. 
In my computer the ini file is at C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7